# Licenses are not properly returned to the license server

Tags: licensing, networking

I've encountered the problem that sometimes network licenses that are managed by a MathLM server are not properly returned to the license server. Even though the Mathematica kernel that requested them is no longer running, they stay blocked until some timeout is reached (I think roughly after an hour).

Usually this happens if I run a calculation on the command line (`math -script foo.m`). This does happen if the kernel is killed and in that case I'm not surprised and also wouldn't see how it can be avoided. But I've also seen this happen when the script exits regularly (by reaching the end of the script or by calling `Quit`). This problem is particularly nasty if I need to run a large number of scripts with relatively short runtimes since then all licenses become blocked, even if the calculations already finished. I can't completely reliably reproduce it, but it happens frequently enough that it is a problem.

I've encountered this with multiple Mathematica versions (at least 12.3.0 and 13.2.1) on Linux and also at two different institutes that are running MathLM servers.

Is this a known problem? Are there workarounds?

Edit: I just want to add an observation: This might be linked to subkernels. I was able to trigger this by just having a script that launches 8 subkernels and does nothing else, i.e. Mathematica just quits once the 8 subkernels are launched:

```
Print[$CommandLine];
LaunchKernels[8];
```

By then running this script in a for loop and running two such for loops in two terminals in parallel, I was able to trigger this behaviour for about one license per 20 invocations.